# Playing a private track with the Soundcloud javascript API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

If I have a private track's url like:

```
https://soundcloud.com/xx/yy/s-tn8o48CxMd0?si=d02497b1821146c5acc313b19f90n4df
```

How can I use the javascript library to load it?

```
soundcloud_player.load(url, {
  auto_play: false,
  single_active: false,
  show_artwork: true
})
```

I'm assuming "s-tn8o48CxMd0" is the secret token. And don't know what "si=" is.

How can I load the track, preferably without needing a client_id since Soundcloud app registrations seem to be locked:

> Due to the high amount of requests recently received, we will no
> longer be processing API application requests at this time. We are
> working to re-evaluate our process to make it more efficient.

Comment: If SC have suspended their API you can't stream the file.